# using moment js to pass in time zone and get hours offset?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want to pass a three-digit time zone string like "GMT" or "EST" and get the offset like "-05:00" as a string from it.

Moment seems to handle it but I couldn't find a way...

Comment: http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/ - using moment timezone `moment().tz("GMT").format("Z");`

Answer (score 0):

This capability you are asking about has been deprecated. Tim Wood in [this thread](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/162#issuecomment-4060027) says:

> The problem is that Date.prototype.toString returns such different results. That is the only place to get the timezone name (PST, CST, EST, etc). If this method is not returning any timezone information (as is the case with FF10 and IE9, there is no way to get it.

In that same thread there are mentions by some people about how they are able to get the abbreviated time zone and consequently pass it to moment but only in certain browsers.